# Folner nets for amenable groups and basis of neighborhoods at $e$

Tags: topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, amenability

Let $G$ be an amenable locally compact group with identity $e$.

Out of curiosity, can we choose a Folner net $(F_i)$ to be a basis of neighborhoods at $e$ for some classes of locally compact groups ?

Comment: No: rather try to prove that if this condition holds, then $G=\{e\}$.